# Merging two different set of list of integer and getting back the set from integer

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

This is a architectural problem scenario
So I have a List of teachers and another list of students.

```
public class Teacher
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public int ClassStandardId { get; set; }
}
```

Now I need to show a drop down list of Teachers and Students combined. If a user selects a person then the program needs to map the Id back to either teachers or students.
Some presumptions/constraints are

1. Names of students and teachers combined are unique. So in the given drop down names will be unique.
2. After selecting a person, only the given Id will go out of the system to different application and when it comes back my application needs to map it to either teacher or students.
3. Id can only be integer.
4. User just want to see the list of all person in a single drop down.

So I might need to generate different set of Ids for example
1. Teacher set will use id as 1<=id<=9999
2. Student set will use id as 10000<=id<=9999999

Is it right? If not, what is the correct structure for the workflow?

Comment: I really don't know why this makes sense but ok - the obvious solution is to create a base-class/interface `Person` having `Id` and `Name`, implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` using the `Id` (and/or `Name`) and  use `HashSet<Person>`

Comment: Thanks for reply. In this case there should be a normalized table in database having just two columns. And if data in tables Teachers and Students are large then the required join may impact the performance. Is it true?

Comment: What is the user interface you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

One of the solutions can be.

1. Having student in one table while teacher in other table.
2. Bring the data in .Net data tables and merge the two tables data
   into one.
3. Create a column with id field in the new table and
   arrange the ids with keyword 's' and 't' e.g. s-1,t-1,s-2,s-43 etc.
4. On other side decode the id to get original id and the nature of the
   id (teacher or student)

I would do it this way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the constraints is that Id can only be integer.

Comment: In the datatable that you'll create in .Net application, you can make a column with type string. Add your formatted ids into that column. In original table it will remain integer

Comment: Actually the other application which will consume data, will accept only integer.

Comment: What will you be sending to the other application,a list of integers and names or just one selected name? If you are arranging the data and setting it against drop down then you can easily decode the integer value from the id string. Use string split function and split the string with '-' or any other delimiter that you'll put.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to propagate this value into other systems then you can not use any hashing type solution because it is not reversible operation. You need some global integer identifier.

I suggest you to create a new table with auto increment integer primary key and reference this table from the Student and Teacher table. Then each time before you create a new student/teacher insert a new record into the "GlobalIdentity" table and use the last generated id as a global identifier.
Do not mark this new column in Student/Teacher table as a foreign key, then you can periodically clean up the GlobalIdentity table.